# How to reset a property inside a JSP file?

Tags: java, class, jsp

I have a small JSP page that uses the following class:

```
public class classApp {

    public static String dir;
    public static String log;

    public classApp (
        String argDir,
        String argLog
    ) {
        ////
        // prep for app dir goes here
        ////

        ////
        // prep for app log goes here
        ////

        dir = argDir;
        log = argLog;
    }

}
```

The class works fine, it does everything I want. I can verify that it has correct values on my main page.

But I don't know to reset the Class Object. Since I set it, it always has been having a value even, after I assign 'null'.

```
<%

public static classApp classapp;

classapp = new classApp (
    request.getContextPath(),
    "testlog"
);

// this works I can see the correct data
out.println(classapp.dir);
out.println(class.log);

// I want to reset it now
classapp = null;

// this still shows the same data
out.println(classapp.dir);
out.println(class.log);

%>
```

Comment: You should not really have java code in your jsp

Comment: Any static variables in a server context is a sign that something's very wrong.

Comment: I do agree that static variables are a bad idea but I have not found another way to do this. I need an app class object that will be used by every function in my web page